# Make a background of plots based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I want to draw plots with conditions. If condition is True then I make background of one of the plots in different color compared to others. But I do not understand why my code is not working.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'wagon' : [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], 'ind' : [55, 55, 65, 65, 78, 78], 'axl1' : [1, 3, 1, 9, 1, 5], 
                   'axl2' : [1, 4, 1, 5, 1, 12], 'dia' : [2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3], 'defects' : ['диаметр', 'диаметр', 'перекос', 'перекос', 'обод', 'обод']})

wags = df['wagon'].unique()
inds = df['ind'].unique()
defect = df['defects'].unique()

for (i, j, k) in tuple(zip(wags, inds, defect)):
    
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize = (5, 5))

    axs[0].plot(df.query(f'wagon == {i}')['axl1'].values, marker = 'o')
    axs[0].set_xlabel('distance')
    
    if df.query(f'wagon == {i}')['dia'][0] > 2:
        axs[1].plot(df.query(f'wagon == {i}')['axl2'].values, marker = 'o')
        axs[1].set_facecolor('0')       
    else:
        axs[1].plot(df.query(f'wagon == {i}')['axl2'].values, marker = 'o')
    
    axs[1].set_xlabel('distance')  
    fig.suptitle(f'Wagon = {i}, Defect = {k}', fontsize = 16)

    plt.show()
```

It throws an error as below:
[image]

So in reality I need a background of plot in the lower right corner with different color as `dia` is greater than 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are indexing the pandas Series wrong in this line:

```
if df.query(f'wagon == {i}')['dia'][0] > 2:
```

For anything after `wagon == 1`, there is no index `0`, so you get a key error.

Instead you can use [`.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) to do integer-location based indexing. From the docs:

> Purely integer-location based indexing for selection by position.
>
> `.iloc[]` is primarily integer position based (from 0 to length-1 of the axis), but may also be used with a boolean array.

So, you can use:

```
if df.query(f'wagon == {i}')['dia'].iloc[0] > 2:
```

and your script works as expected

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
if df.query(f'wagon == {i}')['dia'][0] > 2:
```

throws the `KeyError` because you are trying to access element at index `[0]`, but the `pandas.Series` does not always have that index.
A different approch is to check if *all* elements in `df.query(f'wagon == {i}')['dia']` series do have `dia` greater than 2.
You need to change the `if` statement this way:

```
 if all(df.query(f'wagon == {i}')['dia'] > 2):
```

### Complete Code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.DataFrame({'wagon': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], 'ind': [55, 55, 65, 65, 78, 78], 'axl1': [1, 3, 1, 9, 1, 5],
                   'axl2': [1, 4, 1, 5, 1, 12], 'dia': [2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3],
                   'defects': ['диаметр', 'диаметр', 'перекос', 'перекос', 'обод', 'обод']})

wags = df['wagon'].unique()
inds = df['ind'].unique()
defect = df['defects'].unique()

for (i, j, k) in tuple(zip(wags, inds, defect)):
    
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize = (5, 5))

    axs[0].plot(df.query(f'wagon == {i}')['axl1'].values, marker = 'o')
    axs[0].set_xlabel('distance')

    if all(df.query(f'wagon == {i}')['dia'] > 2):
        axs[1].plot(df.query(f'wagon == {i}')['axl2'].values, marker = 'o')
        axs[1].set_facecolor('0')
    else:
        axs[1].plot(df.query(f'wagon == {i}')['axl2'].values, marker = 'o')

    axs[1].set_xlabel('distance')
    fig.suptitle(f'Wagon = {i}, Defect = {k}', fontsize = 16)

    plt.show()
```

[image]
[image]
[image]